# VS 2015 showing status bar message "Completing the operation you requested..."

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Just upgraded from VS 2012 to 2015.

Builds on complex solutions take a while to get started, with a new status message showing in the status bar that says "Completing the operation you requested..." for 20 - 30 seconds before a build actually starts.  This is different than the old dialog windows saying "Waiting for Background Operation to Complete".  I am unable to tell what is going on and why this message is shown, and how I can avoid it as it seems to be indicating unnecessary work.

Comment: I have the same problem, but it hangs much, much longer (and I can't even cancel it)

Comment: I've run the disk performance monitor and I see tons of disk activity in a temp "shadowcopy" directory as well as two files related to Winnovative.  I have no idea how to fix this and it's killing my productivity.  Every time I go to run a test, I have to wait 30 seconds for the "build" which has nothing to build.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but it's worth a try... open Tools | Options, select Projects and Solutions, Build and Run. Be sure to have 'maximum number of...' set to whatever number of threads your computer can run (not more), output verbosity for MSBuild to 'minimal' and 'log file verbosity' to 'quiet'. I'm curios if it would make a difference.

Comment: Try disabling Nuget. Also you can try removing .suo file as described here: http://superuser.com/questions/800176/visual-studio-ultimate-2013-hangs-with-waiting-for-operation-to-complete-messa

Comment: Why not just install fresh copy of VS 2015?

Comment: Whilst this isn't a proper solution killing vshub.exe in task manager seems to do the trick.

Comment: Stop your website in IIS

Answer (score 0):

Completing the operation you requested takes much time with a screen as below :

[image]

- First of all **inspect the process** with [process monitor tools](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) so that
  you can catch the process that results in system hang.
- If you have installed **Nuget Package**, then try uninstall them
- Secondly , disable **add - ins** if any
- There are times when your operation gets caught by **anti virus**
  programs , have an eye on trying to disable and check the process
  again

  IF the above steps dont have affect , you must install a **new release**
  of VS